# XDocument adds carriage (\r\n, ecaspe characters) return when generating final xml string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, http-response-codes

I need to return IHttpActionResult, Ok(xml).
Variable xml is a string data type. The problem is next...
When the program returns string xml, it adds \r\n for a NewLine, string escape characters ().
I want to return a clean xml string.

**For example, this string i want to return:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <ProxyGlave>
    <Glava ID="530064">
       <DatumIsporuke>1900-01-01T00:00:00</DatumIsporuke>
    </Glava>
    <Glava ID="530065">
       <DatumIsporuke>1900-01-01T00:00:00</DatumIsporuke>
    </Glava>
 </ProxyGlave>
```

**But my program returns this:**

```
     "
     <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n
     <ProxyGlave>\r\n  
        <Glava ID=\"530064\">\r\n    
           <DatumIsporuke>1900-01-01T00:00:00</DatumIsporuke>\r\n
        </Glava>\r\n
        <Glava ID=\"530065\">\r\n    
           <DatumIsporuke>1900-01-01T00:00:00</DatumIsporuke>\r\n
        </Glava>\r\n
     </ProxyGlave>"
```

**Screenshot from Postman tool:**

[image: Screenshot]

**Code which generates string XML:**

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XElement("ProxyGlave",
        from gl in glave
        select
            new XElement("Glava", new XAttribute("ID", gl.DokumentiGlaId),
            new XElement("DatumIsporuke", gl.datum_isporuke)))
);
return Ok(xdoc.ToString());
```

Comment: Do you mean 1) that you want `\n` instead of `\r\n`, or 2) that you don't want to see `\r\n` at all?

Comment: @canton7 , I do not want to see \r\n and escape characters. I want to return clean XML (example in question)

Comment: Why do you think that your xml contains literal `\r\n` characters? Are you viewing it in Visual Studio? It's most likely your editor that's showing the newline characters as an explicit `\r\n`, and your actual XML is absolutely fine. Can you share a screenshot of what exactly is showing you the `\r\n`?

Comment: I'm using Postman to test HTTP request, so, Postman shows me XML return text, in my case, postman shows me XML string inside of Ok() Http status.

Comment: Again, can you share a screenshot, please?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/L1HgtQf/Postman.png

Comment: Please add the code which generates the response

Comment: The returns are not an issue.  They are invisible and yo uare just seing them in the tool that is viewing the xml.  The returns will be ignored.  If you want the Save method not t write the returns use following :            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = false;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("filename", settings);
            XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            doc.Save(writer);

Comment: @jdweng I don't think that's true. See their screenshot of Postman. I tested that exact bit of functionality with a known response, and it didn't escape the newlines. So I think it's the code that's generating the XML

Comment: @canton7 , The code is added!

Comment: That's weird. Do you have any middleware?

Comment: @canton7 Noup. It is okay when I save this XML to the file.xml ( xdoc.Save(@"C:\file.xml");). But in this case, I need to return this XML with HttpStatus Ok(xml).

Comment: I strongly *suspect* the problem is that your response is converting the string into JSON. That's why it has backslashes in front of the quotes, too. It's easy to test that - remove XML from the picture entirely, and return `Ok("first line\r\nsecond line")` and see what happens. That's a string that contains a line break, but no backslashes (they're just in the C# escape sequences).

Comment: Can you provide some code about how do you use IHttpActionResult to return the xml string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Header of the GET request, you need to add Accept key which has value application/xml. 
With that information in a header, the app knows what type of value it needs to return.

[image]